# Node.js Google Sheets API append

Tags: node.js

Below a snippet of my code that works. It is from the Google Example for the Sheets API for node.js and appends sample data to the sheet.

```
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), appendData);
});
```

appendData looks like this:

```
function appendData(auth) {
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: auth,
    ....
```

I am new to JavaScript and I don't understand why appendData on line 2 to doesn't take any arguments.
I would like to add "function appendData(auth, values)" but as soon as I use parantheses when I call appendData I get errors.

Could someone explain this to me?

edit: 
This is the authorize function:

```
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what errors do you get? paste the full code that how are you calling `appendData` function

Comment: The first code snippet is the full code calling the function. When I add parameters to line 2 I get:
Error message: "TypeError: callback is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Your `authorize` function expects 2 arguments, the second one is a function callback. I would suggest to avoid using callbacks today, for several reasons. You can use `async/await` or promises (I will share some snippets later).

Inside the `authorize` function your are calling the callback with `oauth2Client` as a single parameter. Here you can pass your values that would be received in your append data function:

```
function appendData(auth, values) {
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: auth,
    resource: { values },
    ....
```

But please notice you are also passing the callback function as an argument inside `authorize` making this more complicated.

```
getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
```

So instead, I would go for a different approach.

This would be my suggestion for authorization:

```
async function authorize() {
  let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
  if (client) {
    return client;
  }
  client = await authenticate({
    scopes: SCOPES,
    keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  });
  if (client.credentials) {
    await saveCredentials(client);
  }
  return client;
}

async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then you can use this async authorize function

```
// These values could come from anywhere
const values = [["mario", "camacho", "mario.camacho2@gmail.com"]];

async function writeSpreedSheet() {
  const auth = await authorize();
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
  try {
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      spreadsheetId,
      range,
      valueInputOption: "RAW",
      resource: {
        values,
      },
    });
    // Do something with the response
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    return;
  }
}
```